# How to uncheck the radiobuttons when we select date in datepicker?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have created a datepicker using kendo ui, and i'm having some radio buttons. Initially the radio button is set to be as checked , now i need is if i select a date from datepicker i need to uncheck the radio buttons.. below is my code

```
  <input type="radio" id="rdthisweek" name="rdall" value="This Week" onclick="enable()" />This Week
  <input type="radio" id="rdthismonth" name="rdall" value="This Month" onclick="enable()" />This Month
  <input type="radio" id="rdthisquarter" name="rdall" value="This Quarter" onclick="enable()" />This Quarter
```

this is my kendo ui date picker

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("datepicker1")
        //.Events(e=>e.Open("Open"))
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px"  })
    )
```

tell me how to uncheck the radio buttons using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
function startChange() {
   $('input[name="rdall"]')prop('checked',false);
}
```

On selection event of kendo ui datepicker

```
     var start = $("#start").kendoDatePicker({
                    change: startChange
                }).data("kendoDatePicker");
```

Or

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
      .Name("datepicker1")
    //.Events(e=>e.Open("Open"))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px"  })
      .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))  
)
```